# Discrete Math Elements within a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

$\{x \mid x \in\mathbb N,  x \text{ is even, and } 2 < x < 11\}$

Would the elements in this set be $x$ and all positive even integers between $2$ and $10$?

Comment: $x$ is not an element of the set; is only the variable used in the definition that reads : "the set of all (natural) numbers that are even and (strictly) included between $2$ and $11$".

Answer (score 1):

What you posted is what we call defining a set using *set-builder* notation. It's a way of defining a set without having to explicitly list all its elements.

The set in question can be written $\{4, 6, 8, 10\}$; $2$ is not included because we must have $x>2$. That is, $x$ must be an even integer, greater than $2$, and less than $11$. That determines each and every value $x$ can take on, all $x$ such that  $x\in \{4, 6, 8, 10\}$.

Now, we can argue that it is simpler to just list those 4 elements and but brackets around tem. But there are many instances where it's not so easy to do so.

For example, the set $\{x^2\mid x\in \mathbb Z\}$ would be quite laborious to write, since there are infinitely (countably) many perfect squares of integers. Using set builder notation, we can define that the set is all the elements of the form $x^2$, where $x \in \mathbb Z$.